# Read "structured/serialized data" from NSStream

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am developing a game app which will take structured data from a server and make responses based on these data.

I have connected the app to the internet through the NSSream. Specifically, I follow the tutorial of [Apple's guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Streams/Articles/ReadingInputStreams.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002273-BCIJHAGD). So my code looks something like:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)stream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode {
    switch(eventCode) {
        case NSStreamEventHasBytesAvailable:
        {
            if(!_data) {
                _data = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
            }
            uint8_t buf[1024];
            NSInteger len = 0;
            len = [(NSInputStream *)stream read:buf maxLength:1024];
            if(len) {
                [_data appendBytes:(const void *)buf length:len];
                // bytesRead is an instance variable of type NSNumber.
                [bytesRead setIntValue:[bytesRead intValue]+len];
            } else {
                NSLog(@"no buffer!");
            }
            break;
        }
        // continued
```

My problem is: ***"How can I convert the _data to the format I want when it is possible"***. For example, my server will send two types of data. For each data, the first byte is an indicater for the data type (e.g., 1 means data type 1, 2 means data type 2). For the data type 1, an int (4 bytes) is sent as the data itself. For the data type 2, an int (4 bytes) is sent as the size of the following string bytes. For example, if this int is 10, then there will be 10 more bytes sent from the server to form a string for the client.

The code in my Android(Java) app looks like:

```
// dataIn = new DataInputStream(socket.getInputStream());
private void keepPacketRecving(){ // this will be executed in a separate thread
    while(keepRecvThreadRunning) {
        try {
            byte type;
            type = dataIn.readByte();
            if(type == 1){
                int data = dataIn.readInt();
                getTye1Data(data); // callback function for receiving type 1 data (int)
            } else if (type ==2) {
                int dataSize = dataIn.readInt();
                byte[] buf = new byte[dataSize];
                // ... loop to read enough byte into buf ...
                String data = new String(buf);
                getType2Data(data); // callback function for receiving type 2 data (String)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I also notice I can't have a while-loop inside the switch statement to ask inputStream to read more data untile it is enougth because it will hang the thread.

I guess the best way would be always appending all the bytes into the _data (like the example) and has another function to parse the _data? Then the problem is how I can peek bytes from the data and just fetch part of it out (e.g., 10 bytes out of a 20-byte _data).

Is there any wrapper in Objective-C like the DataInputStream in Java?

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use the same strategy with `NSStream` that you're doing with the Android code.  When you know data is available, you could pull off one byte and examine it... then decide how many additional bytes to pull of the stream based on the type.  You don't HAVE to read 1024 bytes off the stream at a time.

Comment: Another strategy is to just use the NSStream to fill the NSData and then signal a higher level piece of code that is parsing your structures from the NSData.

Comment: Hi Scott,

Thanks for your reply. I can't do the android way because I can't "blcok-read" inside the switch statement. For example, I am going to pull another 5 bytes, but there is only 4 available in the NSStream, then I can't read (unless I have a sort of state machine and separate buffers to maintain the status)

Parsing NSData seems the most reasonable to me now, but I notice it is relative hard to do so due to the lack of good wrapper to access bytes in NSData. For example, I might just need few bytes in the NSData (like fetching the 2~5th byte and treat them as a int)

Comment: @Yu-Chih You can access an `NSData`'s `bytes` as an array of bytes directly and do whatever access you need. `memcpy` bytes from the offset you need into whatever structure you want.